# Define product type after importing QArith

Tags: coq

After importing `QArith` in Coq

```
Require Import Coq.QArith.QArith_base.
```

I want to define a product type

```
Parameter T : Type.
Definition TT : Type := T * T.
```

but the `*` is redefined in `QArith`, and I get the error message

```
Error: The term "T" has type "Type" while it is expected to have type "Q".
```

How can I use the original `*`?

Comment: Please provide a syntactically correct code snippet.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I fixed two typos

Comment: It works for me as it is, try `Definition TT : Type := (T * T) % type.`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the `% type` syntax

Comment: I'm more curious about why it does not work for you. Do you have some more stuff in your file? Between the imports and the definition? Also, what Coq version do you use?

Comment: I may have an old version... `coqc --version` gives me `The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (November 2015) compiled on Nov 04 2015 12:56:53 with OCaml 4.02.3`. I installed it with `apt-get install coq` on Ubuntu 16.04. My test file is exactly those three lines (require, parameter, definition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense there is no "original" `*`. Notations can be overloaded and reused and usually Coq is clever enough to pick the right interpretation for a notation. But sometimes you need to explicitly tell Coq what interpretation scope to use.

The reference manual says that ([sect. 12.2](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/syntax-extensions.html#scopes)):

> An interpretation scope is a set of notations for terms with their interpretation. Interpretation scopes provide a weak, purely syntactical form of notation overloading: the same notation, for instance the infix symbol `+`, can be used to denote distinct definitions of the additive operator. Depending on which interpretation scope is currently open, the interpretation is different. Interpretation scopes can include an interpretation for numerals and strings.

Let me mention a useful command to find out more about notations and their interpretation scope: `Locate "*".` will give you the list of things `*` unfolds into, together with the names of interpretation scopes and the default interpretation scope.

Coq as of version 8.4pl4 tries to use the default interpretation scope, which is `Q_scope` in your case -- that's why you see the error. It can be easily fixed e.g. with scope annotation:

```
Definition TT : Type := (T * T) % type.
```

However, more recent Coq versions (like 8.7.0) understand that in that context we should use `type_scope`, so your code snippet works without any modification.